# Simplfy Massive if else statement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simplfy my massive else if statements. Are there better way to get the shorter codes?
Most of the conditions are using different css property and the way inserting/appending to the element..

Thanks for the help!

```
var img = $("<img src='images//anim.gif class='Img'>");

            var cssProp = {'position':'absolute',
                       'z-index':99,
                       'top': topPos,
                       'left': leftPos
            }

//$element var represent all kinds of elements I have in my DOM           

            if($element.attr('id')=='count' || $element.attr('id')=='assign' ){
                img.prependTo($element)          
            }else if($element.is('#title')){
                cssProp.top=+20;
                img.insertBefore($element);

            }else if($element.is('#tab')){
                detail_img = $("<img src='images/anim.gif' id='tab1' class='Img'>");
                detail_img.insertBefore($element.parent());
                detail_img.css(cssProp);

            }else if($element.is('#tab2')){ 
                detail_img = $("<img src='images/anim.gif' id='tab2' class='Img'>");
                detail_img.insertBefore($element.parent());
                detail_img.css(cssProp);         

            }else if ($element.is('#e_btn')){
                cssProp.left=+20;
                cssProp.top=+3;
                img.insertBefore($element);
                img.css(cssProp);

            }else if($element.is('#date_set')){
                img.insertBefore($element);

            }else if($element.is('td')){
                img.prependTo($element).css(cssProp);

            }else if($element.is('#l_title')){
                cssProp.top+=10;
                img.insertBefore($element);
                img.css(cssProp);

            }else if($element.is('#status')){
                cssProp.top =+10;
                img.insertBefore($element).css(cssProp);

            }else if($element.is('label')){
                img.appendTo($element)

            }else if($element.closest('#divTab').length>0){
                ($element.attr('id')=='work')? cssProp.left+=10 : '';
                cssProp.top+=5;
                img.insertBefore($element);
                img.css(cssProp)
           }else{      
                img.insertBefore($element);
                img.css(cssProp)
            }
```

Comment: Do you have a website we can have a look at? It could seem like you need to take a different approach in general.

Comment: first thing i notice is you use  cssProp.left=+20 as opposed to  cssProp.left += 20 is that intentional?

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold sorry I don't. it's a big project and it will takes forever to explain..

Comment: `($element.attr('id') == 'work') ? cssProp.left += 10 : ''` conditional statements like that expect assignments not expressions. i.e: `cssProp.left = ($element.attr('id') == 'work') ? cssProp.left + 10 : cssProp.left`. `''` seems redundant , just use `if($element.attr('id') == 'work'){ cssProp.left += 10 };` instead I guess.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some HTML then? We need a broader context to give you a proper answer I think. But to begin with, why not use CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the number of lines :

- Reduce the expressions inside every `if{}` clause down to one line - this is fairly trivial. Where necessary, use `$.extend()` to manipulate `cssProp`.
- Some expressions are identical, so their `if` conditions can be composited with `||`.
- Remove blank lines.

Doing this, I get the if/else chain down from 49 to 21 lines.

To improve runtime efficiency start off with the following statements :

```
var id = $element.attr('id');
var tag = $element.get(0).tagName;
```

*OK, this adds 2 lines back in*

Then, in the `if` conditions, perform string comparisons on `id` and `tag` rather than use jQuery expressions. The only exception is `if($element.closest('#divTab').length>0)`, which doesn't follow the same pattern.